# Does connecting to one's computer via local router automatically uses the loopback?

Tags: networking, wireshark, localhost, loopback

I have a TCP application that doesn't show up on Wireshark. I read it was because Wireshark is not able to sniff Loopback communication on Windows.

So, instead of connecting to 127.0.0.1, I connected to 192.168.0.14 (which is the same computer), but it's still not showing on Wireshark.

So my question is : Though it seems I communicate to myself via my home router, is it possible that actually I'm not leaving the Loopback ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible that actually I'm not leaving the Loopback ?

Yes.

Most if not all Ethernet devices do not receive their own transmissions, so a machine on an Ethernet can't communicate with itself by sending a packet to their own MAC address on the Ethernet.  Therefore, most IP protocol stacks detect attempts to send to the interface's own IP address and just wrap the packet around internally and don't put it on the network.

Even if other network devices *can* see their own transmissions, the protocol stack won't use that capability - it's just an extra annoyance to have it do so if possible and not do so if it's not possible - and Wi-Fi devices may well have the same limitation.

Some other tools such as [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2011-04&post=RawCap-sniffer-for-Windows-released) [might be able to capture local traffic](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback).

Comment: Would it be possible then to "fake" or to force the connection to exit and come back, for testing purposes ?

Comment: [The Wireshark Wiki article on loopback capturing](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback) seems to claim that there are some routing tricks to do that; I have not tried them, so I don't know whether they work.